# How to Publish and CheckIn MS Project Online file

Tags: vba, ms-project, project-online

Newbie looking for some help. I'm looking for a way to Checkin the Project file on close. The below code seems to publish the project. I did find this link but couldn't get it to work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.checkin

```
Sub PublishandClose()

Application.FileSave
Application.Publish True, Null

End Sub
```